# Spring mvc with boot: Path variable and Request param of type String getting appended with "." at the end

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I created a REST with Spring Mvc and Boot. It worked fine but suddenly I started seeing one peculiar issue.

Whatever I pass in path variable and query param are appended with full stop.

**Controller**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public String test(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name, @RequestParam(value = "key") String key) {
        System.out.println("Path Variable::" + name);
        System.out.println("Request Param::" + key);
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

**Request**
http://localhost:8080/logu?key=msg

**Application Log**

```
2016-10-16 17:15:41.154  INFO 25275 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet  'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 23 ms
Interceptor : PreHandle : Request::/logu
Path Variable::logu.
Request Param::msg.
```

Please help me to understand why . gets appended.

Comment: I copied & pasted your code and I have no dots...

Comment: do you have any configuration related to contentNegotiation, useSuffixPatternMatch... ?

Comment: @Alex My project is having additional modules as well, like camel routes, pushing to elasticsearch and DAO classes. When I create a simple spring boot mvc with above controller it works fine but the problem is with when run this controller with my real project.

Comment: I understand..  you may need to provide more details about other parts of your application (mostly @Configuration classes). It could be related to Apache camel's Configuration..